# How to structure a Firebase Realtime-Database?

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to set up a Google Firebase Realtime Database to store user data. I am really new to Java and Firebase and until now user data gets saved just under the Uid. I now want to have different categories like Users, Posts, Messages... How can I add such a structure to my Database? I will link a Screenshot of my Database. 
I am completely new to those things​ and don't even know in which file I can add such a structure.

[image: Realtime Database Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can structure your database something like this :

> Users :

```
Users -> uid(With users information.)
```

> Posts

```
Posts -> user_id -> post_id(with post details)
```

> Messages :

```
Message -> user_id -> messages (with message and receiver id.)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is exactly the structure I want. Where can I edit it? Is it part of the Java code or can I do it directly at firebase?

Comment: In the java code: [Read and Write Data on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Comment: @Benoit Thanks that answered my question!